# Getting token types in python sqlparse library

Tags: python-3.x, sql-parser

I am wokring on SQL code parser in python for further code analysis. I decided to use "sqlparse" python library and after parsing the text I would like to know particular token type such as "Identifier", "Keyword", ....

Globally after running:

```
 raw = 'select * from foo join fuu on foo.id = fuu.id where id in (select id from bar);'
 statements = sqlparse.parse(raw)
 print(statements[0].tokens)
```

I can see:

```
[<DML 'select' at 0x298851E3DC0>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x2988523C400>, <Wildcard '*' at 0x2988523C100>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x2988523C160>, <Keyword 'from' at 0x2988523C1C0>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x2988523CB20>,
```

Where it is visible whether the token is "whitespace" or any other type. But it is only visible when printing whole list in print statement.
How do I get info in code whether it is Whitespace, Keyword or something else?

I was trying multiple functions from library, but I still cannot get it.
(Documentation of the library)
https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/sqlparse/latest/sqlparse.pdf

There exists something such as ttype, but it doesn't work.
One token is type <class 'sqlparse.sql.Token'>.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to sqlparse myself, but here is my solution. If you know how to improve it, please leave a comment!

```
def get_token_type(sql_query: str = None, tokens: list = None, type_list: list = None) -> list:
statements = tokens or sqlparse.parse(sql_query.strip())[0]
type_list = type_list or []
for token in statements:
    if token.ttype:
        type_list.append(token.ttype)
    else:
        get_token_type(tokens=token.tokens, type_list=type_list)
return type_list
```